# Paracol/minipage caption problems

Tags: minipage, subfig, paracol

I am trying to have two images side by side, each should have its own caption and numbering. I tried to approach this with paracol and minipage. Both of them seem to have its own flaws. The code is as follows:

```
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]{images/img_size_dependency.pdf}
        \caption{The relation between image size and $AP@.5$}
        \label{fig:img_sizes}
    \end{figure}
    \switchcolumn
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]{images/training_set_dependency.pdf}
        \caption{Mean average precision based on the size of training set}
        \label{fig:training_set_sizes}
    \end{figure}
\end{paracol}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]{images/img_size_dependency.pdf}
        \captionof{figure}{The relation between image size and $AP@.5$}
        \label{fig:img_sizes}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]{images/training_set_dependency.pdf}
        \captionof{figure}{Mean average precision based on the size of training set}
        \label{fig:training_set_sizes}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Results for those lines as code are the following: Single caption for minipage and not incrementing counter for paracolumn (even thought I added this line: \globalcounter{figures} ). Do you have any suggestions how to solve this.
[image: minipage]

[image: paracolumn]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the `floatrow` package.

Comment: I checked that, but it seems to add subcaption to each figure and both of them will have one common caption. This is not exactly what I am looking for. Plus the solution with paracol and minipage should work normally (I think).

Comment: Not necessarily. What you describe is valid for the `subfloatrow`environment, not for `floatrow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo of how to get it with the `floatrow` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{floatrow}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{floatrow}[2]
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Marie \v{C}erminova, known as Toyen: \emph{She sleeps} (1937)}}%
       {\includegraphics{LaDormeuse}}\qquad
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Piero di Cosimo: \emph{Portrait of Simonetta Vespucci} (ca 1480)}}%
      {\includegraphics{Piero_di_Cosimo_3}}
    \end{floatrow}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. The problem is, that the structure is reliant on the package float. I hope I will find a workaround (for example make minipage or paracol work properly).

Comment: @lukášKunt: Did you try loading  `float` *after* `floatrow?

Comment: It works!!! Thank you

Comment: Fine! I'm glad your problem is solved.